# libuuid don't link on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, build, ubuntu-12.04, ld, vhd

I'm trying to build [VHDTool](https://github.com/andreiw/vhdtool) on Ubuntu 12.04 but it's failing when linking:

```
gcc -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -g2   -c -o     vhdtool.o vhdtool.c
gcc -luuid  vhdtool.o   -o vhdtool
vhdtool.o: In function `vhd_footer':
/root/vhdtool/vhdtool-master/vhdtool.c:456: undefined reference to `uuid_generate'
/root/vhdtool/vhdtool-master/vhdtool.c:457: undefined reference to `uuid_unparse'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [vhdtool] Error 1
```

The packages uuid-dev and libuuid1 are installed, ¿is there any way to fix the Makefile?

```
CC      := gcc
CFLAGS  := -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -g2
LDFLAGS := -luuid

all: vhdtool

vhdtool: vhdtool.o
vhdtool.o: vhdtool.c

clean:
        rm vhdtool vhdtool.o
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in the Makefile. Replace `LDFLAGS` with `LDLIBS` in the third line.